# Adverts not appearing on my Android App - Google AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have made an android application and put adverts in using Google AdMob.

On Eclipse's Graphical Layout there is a white rectangle which says 'Ads by Google' in it, which shows that it has been set up properly.

However, when I run the app on the simulator and in real life, nothing shows up. Why would this be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how you can used admob,it means using jar or using google play services?

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have setup your Android Application properly with Ads, go over the following steps and ensure that you have done them correctly.

1. GoogleAdMob Jar in your libs folder
2. GoogleAdMob Activity in your manifest
3. GoogleAd AdView in your main activity XML file, with your adunitId correctly inputted
4. And Ensure your class in which your AdMob is coded in is correct.

Let me know if these steps help you or not.